# How to have URI template with optional variable with path

Tags: ruby, uri, site-prism, uritemplate, addressable-gem

I am using site prism to create an page object that has a possible 2 urls.
Site_prism uses Addressable::Template, and this uses the URI template RFC 6570.

The required page contains a list of elements, but can have none as well, and from this logic 2 possible URLs are defined.

If the page has no elements the URL is `example.com/foo`
If the page has elements, it redirects selecting the first to `example.com/foo/1/bar`

I am trying to create a url template for the page so that I can have one of two possible outputs.

case 1 : `Page.new.load` => `example.com/foo`
case 2 : `Page.new.load(id: 1)` => `example.com/foo/1/bar`

The solutions I have got so far are:
`set_url '/foo{/id,path}'` `Page.new.load(id: 1, path: 'bar')`
This works for case 1 but not case 2 as it requires 2 variables.

`set_url '/foo{/path*}'` `Page.new.load(path: [1, 'path'])`
Again this works for case 1 but not case 2.

What I need is a uri template that has a path appended to it but only if the variable is present.
something like: `/foo{/id,path("bar")}`

A variable with a default value, or a path that is only present with a defined variable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SitePrism has had a lot of updated regarding the addressable templates, however you're posting after all of those have gone in.

Have you tried with the later versions of site_prism and addressable (Something after 2.12 for site_prism and 2.5 for addressable).

If not could you open a defect / feature request on Github, as this sounds like something we "should" support. https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism/issues